# Synchronize Signal contacts on signal-desktop in Ubuntu 18 from Signal on Ubuntu Touch (Fairphone2)

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-touch, signal

I installed the Signal app on my Fairphone2 running Ubuntu Touch.
Contacts were correctly imported from contacts list to the app.
I installed the Signal desktop client for Ubuntu 18 on my computer with the following webpage: https://www.signal.org/fr/download/.
I can run signal-desktop on my computer and the link procedure between phone app and signal-desktop seems to work.

But then my contacts list on signal-desktop stays empty and the import procedure for contacts ends with the error message:

{"name":"log","hostname":"myhostname","pid":mypid,"level":50,"msg":"Top-level unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failure: Ask sender to update Signal and resend.","time":"2019-06-14T11:58:03.215Z","v":0}

Has anyone been able to import a contact list from any Phone and OS to signal-desktop on Ubuntu 18?

Thanks a lot

Comment: why aren't you reporting this to signal ?

Comment: Because Signal teams work on a lot of technical tickets and the combination Ubuntu + Fairphone + Ubuntu Phone might not be treated in priority. So if anyone already encountered the issue and solved it, I would be happy to ear how and I would send the full user experience report to Signal.
Also anyone having the same issue would be glad to find the answer quickly on StackExchange, so I chose to ask the question here.
And of course if nobody here can help, I will report the issue to Signal on https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues

Comment: The `signal` tag is not appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10  I have used the following:

```
sudo snap install signal-desktop
```

and it works fine.

If you need to copy Signal data from one computer to another, just `tar` everything under `/home/user/snap/signal-desktop/`.